# Is there a statistical differing interpretation between match and fit?

Tags: interpretation, fitting, matching, definition

I've seen the terms *matching/match* and *fitting/fit* used almost interchangeably when discussing models goodness of fit, observed vs simulated data matching, etc.

Is there a difference in interpretation between these terms that should be taken into account or are they more or less synonyms (in the strict statistical sense)?

Comment: Do you have any citations where this occurs?  I am interested in seeing where they actually interchange the two.

Comment: Hi Dan, I don't have _specific_ citations since this question was mostly based on my own recollections of having seen it somewhere and my own need to clearly separate the definition of those words. You can check this link http://goo.gl/7n0rJC for a list of articles with both words used in the abstract of astronomic articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those terms mean different things (at least in the statistics community) and should not be used interchangeably.

---

**Matching** is a statistical technique which is used to evaluate the effect of a treatment by comparing the treated and the non-treated units in an observational study or quasi-experiment (i.e. when the treatment is not randomly assigned). The goal of matching is, for every treated unit, to find one (or more) non-treated unit(s) with similar observable characteristics against whom the effect of the treatment can be assessed. By matching treated units to similar non-treated units, matching enables a comparison of outcomes among treated and non-treated units to estimate the effect of the treatment without reduced bias due to confounding.

---

**Fitting** is the process of constructing a curve, or mathematical function, that has the best fit to a series of data points, possibly subject to constraints. Curve fitting can involve either interpolation, where an exact fit to the data is required, or smoothing, in which a "smooth" function is constructed that approximately fits the data. A related topic is regression analysis, which focuses more on questions of statistical inference such as how much uncertainty is present in a curve that is fit to data observed with random errors. Fitted curves can be used as an aid for data visualization, to infer values of a function where no data are available, and to summarize the relationships among two or more variables.